# How Do I Update an Old VB Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a VB program a few years ago.  I don't know what version VB (or should I say Visual Studio) I used.
Today I tried to make some changes.  I discovered I didn't have any version of VS installed on this computer.  I have no idea how that happened.  I found folders for VS 9.0, 10.0 in one area of Program Files.  I found folders for VS (no version), VS 8, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,and 15.0. In another area of Program Files.  The folders have all kinds of files in them but I couldn't find an executable.   The Control Panel list showed no versions of VB or VS were installed. 
I found a CD with Visual Basic 2010 Express on it so I installed it.
When I tried to open my program I got a warning that it was going to have to update it and would make a backup.
Then it opened and I got so many errors I have no idea what to do.
Oh, I guess I should mention, I'm just a retired engineer that enjoys doing projects like this for myself.  I am not a professional programmer.

I suppose the quickest way to make the changes I need is to figure out which version of VB I used and find it and install it.
Is that a good idea or is there a better solution?

Note I am coding on a 64 bit processor but I want the code to run on a 32 bit Windows 8.1 tablet.  The existing version did before.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: You can download the Visual Studio Community Edition for free and try it.  It doesn't have all the features of the Professional or Enterprise edition, but it it's free.  Most things should be compatible, unless it was VB6 or earlier.  You can target x86 to get 32-bit.

Comment: It could very well have been VB6.  What do I do then?

Comment: Depends how many lines of code. Your free license to VS2017 includes a trial license for VBUC (Visual Basic Upgrade Companion) by Mobilize.net. It’s good for a project with up to 10,000 lines of code. They will also help you with the conversion. My experience with the conversion software was fair, but their support (especially for something “free”) was not much short of amazing.

Comment: The upgrade and high numbers of errors suggest that it was in fact a VB6 (or earlier) program.  You may struggle to find a copy of VB6, or you could work your way through the upgraded code in VSCE and fix all the errors. You might see it as an enjoyable challenge; only you can say. I'd guess, though, that many of the errors are essentially the same thing, so when you know how to fix one, you'll immediately be able to fix a lot more; so don't let the sheer number put you off.

Comment: @peterG, the fact that it upgraded at all precludes it from being VB6.  VS 2008 was the last version of VS that included the upgrade wizard from VB6 apps.

Comment: What are the extensions of the files in the original project?  That should tell us whether it was VB6 or VB.NET at least.  If there is SLN and VBPROJ files then it's definitely VB.NET.  The code files will, I think, be BAS files for VB6 and VB files for VB.NET.  Are there any DESIGNER.VB files, which would indicate VB 2005 or later?

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks, good catch.

Comment: You should also be able to open the SLN and/or VBPROJ files in a text editor and see what version of VS they were created in.

Comment: Well, I bit the bullet and drug out the CPU I used to write the code.  It seems that I was using VB5.  So that is pretty far back.  But it looks like I have the install files (setup.exe , etc).  I wonder if I should (a) Just do the updates on the old CPU, (b) Try to install VB5 on this Windows 8.1 machine or get the latest "Free" VS and regenerate the program in the latest VB.  Decisions, Decisions, Decisions.  Thanks